# Is Sweaver module compatible with Domain Access module?

Tags: domain-access

I'm configuring a [Domain Access](https://drupal.org/project/domain) website and having some issues on making [Sweaver](https://drupal.org/project/Sweaver) module working as it suppose to be. I see that Sweaver back end is configurable based on domain. What about the switch theme feature? Is there any known compatibility issue between these two modules?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It doesn't work because it saves all the data files in the same place and all the sites will have your same changes. The admin settings maybe able to be changed based on the domain but code that controls your CSS changes doesn't change based on the current domain.

This is with Drupal 6.